# Notation or verbiage for the opposite of 'iff'?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Given the statement $X \implies Y$ and $Y \implies X$, we have the common notation $X \iff Y$. Ok so is there an opposite of this concept? Suppose I have $X$ doesn't imply $Y$, nor does $Y$ imply $X$...i.e. neither implies the other. What would you say or write for this? Whats the correct word?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are *independent* of each other.

Comment: $\lnot(x \leftrightarrow y) \equiv \lnot(x\rightarrow y) \lor \lnot (y \rightarrow x)\not\equiv \lnot(x \rightarrow y) \land \lnot(y \rightarrow x$. Note that this is a disjunction of negations, not a conjunction. So the negation/opposite of $x\leftrightarrow y$ does not forbid one from implying the other; it forbids that both $x, y$ imply the other.

Answer (score 1):

In logic, $X\,$ XOR $\,Y$, which we can denote $X\oplus Y,\,$ is the negation of $X \leftrightarrow Y$.

That is, $$X\oplus Y \equiv \lnot (X \leftrightarrow Y)$$

There are a number of common ways in which $X\oplus Y$ is defined: $$X\oplus Y \equiv (X \lor Y)\land \lnot (X\land Y)$$

Alternatively, $$X \oplus Y  \equiv (X \land \lnot Y) \lor (\lnot X \land Y)$$

Comment: It is not clear to me that the original question is about propositional logic. I took $X$ and $Y$ to be sentences in natural language, rather than Boolean variables.

Answer (score 0):

In boolean algebra notation, one can write $X=Y$ which is equivalent to saying that $X\Leftrightarrow Y$.  The opposite of that is 
$$
X \neq Y
$$

And the wording equivalent to the opposite of iff is "unless", as in

$n\in \Bbb{N}$ is even *iff* $\exists m\in \Bbb{N} : n = 2m$

$n\in \Bbb{N}$ is odd *unless* $\exists m\in \Bbb{N} : n = 2m$